# selenium error - Unable to locate select element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Please find the html code below :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
      <select ui-select2="ui-select2" name="dealer" id="selected_dsd" ng-init="delegate.init()" ng-model="selectedMainStoreTest" ng-change="delegate.getBranchDealers()">
        <option value="">{{'manageChargeCodes.form.fields.choose' |translate}}</option>
        <option ng-repeat="dealer in mainStoreDealerList" value="{{dealer}}">{{dealer.id}} - {{dealer.name}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

From the below code i will get some list of options, and i have to get the selected values using XPath

```
<option ng-repeat="dealer in mainStoreDealerList" value="{{dealer}}">{{dealer.id}} - {{dealer.name}}</option>
```

Please find by below code that am using to get the selected value

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"select2-result-label-90\"]")
private WebElement mainStoreDealersSelector;

public void selectMainStoreDealers(String mainStoreDealer) {
     System.out.println("Xpath--->"+mainStoreDealersSelector);
     selectFromDropDown(mainStoreDealersSelector, mainStoreDealer);
     System.out.println("Completed....");
}
```

And am getting the below results while am printing it.

```
Xpath--->Proxy element for: org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator@d93a6a5
```

and its getting failed with the below error :

```
Results :

Tests in error:
  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"select2-result-label-90\"]"}
Command duration or timeout: 100.29 seconds
```

Comment: No element seems to have this id in the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **"ID" selector** ,sometimes when xpath fails we use CSS properties to select an element.

```
@FindBy(id="selected_dsd")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no element with `select2-result-label-90` id in your HTML. If you are trying to select the "select" element, the proper xpath would be

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='selected_dsd']")
```